# Determine when OS X was installed?

Tags: macos

I am going to be reinstalling OS X and I was wondering if there was a method for determining when the base (**OS X 10.6**) Operating System was installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pkgutil` command to get info on the packages installed on your Mac; `pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem` should list the installation time for the base system. But it'll be in the form of seconds since the unix epoch, so you need to use `date -r` to convert that into a human-readable format. Here's an example:

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem
package-id: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem
version: 10.6.0.1.1.1249367152
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1306707387
groups: com.apple.snowleopard-repair-permissions.pkg-group com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
$ date -r 1306707387
Sun May 29 15:16:27 PDT 2011
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the question a bit -- I didn't realize the OS had been updated since 10.6. Unfortunately, the receipts system doesn't generally records for more than one version of a specific installer package (as defined by the package ID), so if you've installed more than one version of "com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem" it'll only have records from one of them. But you can find the oldest package you have records of, and there's a good chance it's a holdover from the initial system installation:

```
pkgutil --pkgs | while read pkgname; do
    installtime="$(pkgutil --pkg-info "$pkgname" | awk '/^install-time:/ { print $2 }')"
    echo "$installtime $pkgname"
done | sort -g | head
```

(Then use `date -r` to convert to the timestamp to a readable form, as before.)

Comment: Is there a similar command for later versions of `OS X`?

Comment: I actually got the response `No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem' found at '/'.` I'm not exactly worried, everything appears to be fine - but would you know any reason why? Initial OS long-gone, was Snow Leo originally, now Yosemite; though in a direct line, no clean install at any time.

Comment: @Tetsujin Try `com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemBinaries`, or `pkgutil --pkgs` to list them all.

Comment: Best I can get is `version: 10.10.0.1.1.1411459885` which I initially thought might be Darwin version, but it's not, it's OS X version, & `install-time: 1420465300` which is Jan 2015. Groups are actually same as your initial post, though the--pkgs gave way too much to wade through... No worries, anyway, I'll live with it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin if it had 10.6 installed on it (or any of the other versions that included something with that package ID), it should have a record of that. I'm not sure why that wouldn't be found. I've edited the question with a way to find the oldest package records on the system; see what that shows.